# File upload error in php on hosting service

Tags: javascript, php, html, filesystems

Guys I am very frustrated today because of my fliles error in php

It is not uploading the file to my folder and there are no error message

Actually I am Creating a Chat website so I have completed it but the problem is in my server it is not working..

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
if (isset($_GET['room']) && isset($_GET['room']) ) {
    if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
        require 'db_connect.php';

        $room = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['room']);
        $room = htmlentities($room);

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hidden']);
        $name = htmlentities($name);
        
        $img = $_FILES['img'];
  
        $imgName = $img['name'];
        $imgAddr = $img['tmp_name'];
        $imgErr = $img['error'];
        $imgSize = $img['size'];
  
        if ($imgErr == 0) {
    
            if ($imgSize<=2000000) {
                $fileExt = explode('.',$imgName);
                $fileExt_check = end($fileExt);
                $allowedExts = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');
    
                if (in_array($fileExt_check,$allowedExts)) {
                    if(copy($imgAddr,$upload_dir.'/ImgsSended/'.$imgName)){
                        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                        $date = date("h:i A d F - Y");
                        
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `myMessages` ( `msg_type` , `msg`, `room`, `name`, `stime`) VALUES ('file','imgsSended/$imgName', '$room', '$name', '$date')";
                        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        if ($res) {
                            echo '
                                alert("Image Sended Successfully");
                                location.href = "rooms.php?roomname='.$room.'";
                            ';
                        }
                    }else {
                        echo '
                            alert("Some Error Occurred While Sending Your Image");
                            location.href = "rooms.php?roomname='.$room.'";
                        ';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '
                        alert("This file is not supported - \n Only\n jpg \n png\n jpeg\n and\n gif \are supported");
                        location.href = "rooms.php?roomname='.$room.'";
                    ';
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }else{
                echo '
                    alert("Your File Size is Too Big");
                    location.href = "rooms.php?roomname='.$room.'";
                ';
            }
        }else{
            echo '
                alert("your File is currpted");
                location.href = "rooms.php?roomname='.$room.'";
            ';
        }
    }else{
        echo '
            alert("No Image Selected");
            location.href = "rooms.php?roomname='.$room.'";
        ';
    }
} else{
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>
</script>
```

ImgsSended is my folder name In which I want to upload images

And I am here a post request in this page from my file upload form

MY Form

```
     <form action="sendFile.php?room=<?php echo $roomname?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="nameHidden">
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2" name="sendFile">Send</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not an adequate description of your problem. What exactly is not working? Are there any error messages?

Comment: It is not uploading the file to my folder no error message

Comment: And always return a same alert as I wrote in my code Some Error Occurred While sending your image

Comment: The only thing you send back to the user is a couple of rows of javascript: an `alert` and an attempt to change the window url. But this is a response to a basic form submit, so the browser is expecting an entire HTML page back.

Comment: Instead of `copy()` use `move_uploaded_file()`. Your script is wide open for sql injection and totally insecure.

Comment: Please can you suggest me to be safe from SQL injection

Comment: Yes. Read the documentation about prepared statements. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Please can you help me with this after changing copy to move..... It now Also not working It is alering me now also some error occurred

Comment: @Vinayak And what does the error say then? Errors often tell you useful things, so you need to share them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn how to debug PHP code.

As you said your `copy()` or `move_uploaded_file()` condition is always false, thus the else condition comes into force. This happens, because `copy()` or `move_uploaded_file()` return false, if the file couldn 't be moved. In most cases this happens, because the given file is not valid.

In this case you can debug your data. Just test, what data the contents you are using contain. Is the filename valid? Is the destination valid? Is everything accessable?

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($imgAddr, $upload_dir . '/ImgsSended/' . $imgName);
echo "</pre>";
```

Now you can see the contents of what you 're trying to do. What data contains the `$imgAddr` variable. Is it a valid filename? What contains the destination? Is it a valid path to an existing directory? Can PHP access this directory?

You can test the existence with the following line of code.

```
is_dir($upload_dir . '/ImgsSended/');
```

If this returns `true`, the given directory exists and this could not be the reason for the error.

It 's always about debugging. Errors have to be read and understand. They contain useful informations for you.